# What's the proper way to handwrite a lowercase letter A?

Tags: orthography, handwriting

[image: both ways of writing a lowercase letter A]

There were two ways of writing the letter A, as seen in figure 1 and figure 2. I'm a non-native English speaker and I was explicitly taught to write figure 2 by my Irish teacher. However, on computers and fonts, I've almost never seen figure 2 actually used. In real life I notice about 75% of people use figure 2.

I tried to google more on the subject, but google never understands my search properly, like "correct way of writing lowercase letter a"

So is there a correct way to write lowercase A? Which one is it? Which version do they teach in schools in English countries? What about non-English countries who teach English as a second language? How did such a large difference even develop?

Comment: Handwritten script often looks different from typefaces, in English and in other languages. Another example is the lowercase "g"; the typical form in serif typefaces, with a closed bottom loop, is essentially never used in handwriting.

Comment: Are you referring to non-cursive standalone ***a*** ?

Comment: @sumelic  It's widely used in various calligraphic hands, which is why you see it in print faces.

Comment: [This is how handwriting is taught here](http://mathcover.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cursive-handwriting-practice-cursive.png), and this is [just the letter a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#/media/File:A_cursiva.gif). This is all explained on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#Typographic_variants). If that Wikipedia link does not answer your question, please clarify what parts are still a mystery by editing your question.

Comment: Neither of those is how you "write" (using a pencil/pen) the lower-case letter a.  First off it depends on whether you are "printing" (using "block letters") or "writing" (using script/cursive).

Comment: See https://www.google.com/search?q=fond+vs.+handwritten+a&tbm=isch&source=iu&pf=m&ictx=1&fir=SqoQW5OkAsnKnM%253A%252C-kYBRnhzX-XdlM%252C_&usg=__ickhzoFFMvyhhGlCcAm3BnlsgF8%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-obCS6JnXAhVDl1QKHfjLAFIQ9QEIKjAA#imgrc=RFehIIAeX2M7CM:

Comment: I would be very surprised if the proportion of people using the "two-storey" *a* as a model for handwriting was as high as 25%.

Comment: @tchrist Wherever your 'here' is, we do things differently in my 'here'. http://www.unask.com/website/handwriting/new_web_pages/acquisition.htm and more chaotically. Apparently my handwriting is a mix of print script, looped cursive, Nelson round hand and italic.

Comment: There's no "correct" or "proper" way; either 1 or 2 is fine.

Comment: Didn’t you mean ’  ℴ  ℴ   ℴ  ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question simply: The proper (or at least normal) way to write "a" in handwriting is to write it "ɑ" without the arc above the loop.

The two ways to write lower-case a are called double-storey A (a) and single-storey A (ɑ). Single-storey is used for *italics* in most fonts. But why are there two different As?

Back in ye olde days there were many ways to write a lower-case A. (The same went for other letters, for example þ was later written "y", hence "ye olde days".) After a while there were two emerging winners: a and ɑ. One won the handwriting competition, and the other won the printing competition. And so it has been ever since.

Sources:

- [A: Typographic_variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A#Typographic_variants)
- [Styles of the Lowercase "a"](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/42112)
- [Why Are There 2 Ways to Write the Lowercase Letter ‘A’?](https://web.archive.org/web/20151014092356/http://upvoted.com/2015/10/13/why-are-there-2-ways-to-write-the-lowercase-letter-a/)

Note that all my sources are second-hand/Wikipedia, so take them with a grain of salt.

Comment: Do you have any citation to add so that we can see the veracity of what you tell us ?

Comment: @NigelJ Now I have added the articles I've based my answer on.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the question of "proper," you can get a clear idea of what is *taught* (at least in the US) by googling, e.g., "[alphabet line](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&sxsrf=AOaemvIA9EugeFGAuk6aG7U8VXG95SC1ZQ:1637326050754&source=univ&tbm=isch&q=alphabet%20line%20for%20classroom&fir=YB62JIG8xQGThM%252CqWVy6ZMyH2lW1M%252C_%253BqfP_6Gdn-TfJSM%252CmGcZ85ApPCMsnM%252C_%253BzIsoX96IzsP1nM%252CwMkSgrww7WeCHM%252C_%253BwCmRAyGxeRMIiM%252CmGcZ85ApPCMsnM%252C_%253BUF8aQ8irHSyemM%252CBcSmwp-NPv0DdM%252C_%253BLu1d-VnQcopZTM%252Cb_ECT7EU2PwFVM%252C_%253BWcte5YTZeO_6GM%252Cuz_J_g1leCQGgM%252C_%253Bsg7gbVtBKCwgDM%252CUx8tshMgY_APfM%252C_%253B2FSCfmuwcWJB-M%252CPhW7K4f_h7CEcM%252C_%253BzCNcnTnfOhiSeM%252Cc1DX3RsR7LRSKM%252C_%253BNiKYlABH2Ul2uM%252CmGcZ85ApPCMsnM%252C_%253BY-DUQEMIIQPUqM%252Cc1DX3RsR7LRSKM%252C_%253BDRMnZ55h3tlrzM%252CV_tG2NT7WaedfM%252C_%253BRmG5ebDFkeHfPM%252Ce3NbeExTzzOiaM%252C_%253BQsTKpzD4sjoLoM%252C_KL2rZi6YtjxbM%252C_&usg=AI4_-kQWsZ0JPoKhlf006tNYMl4_WU5f_Q&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2sYvtuqT0AhWHVTABHVRpC1gQ7Al6BAgCEFA&biw=1004&bih=577&dpr=1.25)" or "[alphabet strip for classroom](https://www.google.com/search?q=alphabet%20strip%20for%20classroom&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjI84udxKT0AhXoQUIHHWJSC30Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=alphabet%20strip%20for%20classroom&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBggAEAgQHjIGCAAQCBAeMgYIABAIEB4yBggAEAgQHjIECAAQGDoHCCMQ7wMQJzoGCAAQBxAeOggIABAIEAcQHlD-CVjLEWCZE2gAcAB4AIABfYgB5wSSAQM2LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=t6aXYYi8FOiDieoP4qSt6Ac&bih=577&biw=1004&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911)" (the model letters put up in classrooms). I believe every one of the images that came up for me has some form of the OP's version 2 for a printed  *a*.

(At some point as an adult I switched over to the other *a* (fig. 1), perhaps thinking there was less chance of my *a* being mistaken for an *o*.)

Comment: ℋℴ  ℴ     ℴ ℴ    ℴ  ℴ? :) Your googles only show childhood   like for kindergarteners, not adult writing in a normal  .  There are certainly formal   that use a two-storey a, like those seen in [uncial hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncial_script), but these are not taught to children, who learn cursive writing using something more akin to the familiar [secretary hands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_hand) that developed later.

Comment: @tchrist I only meant to explain why the fig. 2 *a* may be *more common* in hand-*printing*, not printed (book) fonts. I thought that's what the question was about. Cursive is another topic and I agree with you, a two-storey *a* doesn't figure in. If the question was about cursive, I misunderstood and I'll delete my answer. The OP does ask about teaching.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you're right. Sometime over the past century people have started to conflate the meanings of printing and writing, and of handwriting vs movable type.

Comment: Indeed, and we recently had the question  [What's the difference between print and write](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/577933/whats-the-difference-between-print-and-write), i.e., printed vs. cursive.