# What's the difference between print and write?

Tags: meaning

The specific example comes from a Sherlock Holmes story:

> Yes, sir; prints it in pencil.

> Printing is a clumsy process. Why not write?

What is the difference between print and write in this case? Could writing possibly employ the use of a pen, while printing a pencil?

Comment: "Writing" often means *cursive writing* After Holmes asks "Why not write? What would it suggest, Watson?” Watson replies “That he desired to conceal his handwriting.”

Comment: And "print" means "write using capital letters"

Comment: Many forms in English have two places to put one's name: One says: PRINT NAME and the other will say: SIGN NAME.  The first is write in caps and the second is write in cursive. Nowadays, many young people can't use cursive, so I wonder: How do they sign their names at the bottom of forms or documents? Hmmm

Comment: Although a form may want you to print in all caps, the definitions of *print* I've looked at do not specify that.

Comment: @Lambie: I believe that young folk scrawl a signature onto a tablet (you know, one of those little computer things, not like the tablets Moses brought down from the mountain) using a sausage-like finger as a stylus.

Comment: Note, the distinction was stronger in Doyle's day. Today, assuming that both sentences talk about writing by hand, the distinction in the second sentence would confuse many as it has you, and further clarification like "write longhand" or "in cursive" would be needed.

Comment: Yes, I would understand _printing_ to refer to forming each letter separately, not necessarily using block capitals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the past "writing" usually meant cursive writing for something handwritten. After Holmes asks "Why not write? What would it suggest, Watson?” Watson replies “That he desired to conceal his handwriting.” (*[The Adventure of the Red Circle](https://www.pagebypagebooks.com/Arthur_Conan_Doyle/The_Adventure_of_the_Red_Circle/The_Adventure_of_the_Red_Circle_p2.html)*)

My print Collins documents this sense:

**write** (v.)

> **6.** To write (words) in cursive as opposed to printed style.

as does the collegiate *Webster's New World Dictionary*:

> **2.** To form or inscribe (words) in cursive style: opposed to print.

The print *New Oxford American Dictionary* has:

> (Intrans.) Write in a cursive hand, as opposed to printing individual letters.

*However, I haven't yet found this sense in the OED or in an online dictionary.* When I grew up, this was a distinction made in school: *write* meant cursive writing as opposed to *print*.

---

This [form](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mytinger_Casselberry_Inc_V_Numanna_Labor/oQIm8UWB1XcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22write%20do%20not%20print%22&pg=PA50&printsec=frontcover) from the 1950s has a line for the Purchaser's Signature with the instruction "(WRITE DO NOT PRINT)"

Other examples of "Write do not print" on forms: [Ex. 1](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Criminal_Investigation_Standards/OylaAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22write%20do%20not%20print%22&dq=%22write%20do%20not%20print%22&printsec=frontcover) [Ex. 2](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Driver_Education/-3tyPIzE92MC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22write%20do%20not%20print%22&dq=%22write%20do%20not%20print%22&printsec=frontcover)

"Please **write** (DO NOT PRINT) the following statement. Sign and date." appears in a 2002 [Official LSAT Prep Test](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Official_LSAT_PrepTest/4cLXAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22write%20do%20not%20print%22&dq=%22write%20do%20not%20print%22&printsec=frontcover)

> But we took the gas bill over and found the appropriate desk. You had
> to be able to **write your name or print it**, and I was frightened
> because I never had the Spencerian copperplate hand that of course all
> the girls picked up. But with my tongue sticking out in concentration, I wrote my name, showed the gas bill, and got a temporary library card. [Caterine Burns; *The Moth*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Moth/jRGZAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=said%20write%20your%20name%20but%20i%20printed%20it&pg=PT119&printsec=frontcover)

> Please **write or print** so that your writing may be read by someone
> who is not familiar with your handwriting.
> ...
> Again, you may use **cursive writing** or you may **print**.
> [E. Silas et al.; *Cracking
> the SSAT & ISEE*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cracking_the_SSAT_ISEE/uwf9WT02MugC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Write%20or%20print%22&pg=PA682&printsec=frontcover)

---

**longhand** (n.) presents a similar ambiguity:

> a: Characters or words written out fully by hand
>
> b: Cursive writing
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/longhand)

---

As far as I can determine, the verb **print** does not necessarily  mean in all caps (unless so specified):

> To write in letters shaped like those of ordinary roman text type
> [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/print)

where *roman (text)* means not in italics, i.e., any standard print font or letterforms.

> Write (text) clearly without joining the letters.
>
> *Print your name and address on the back of the check* [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/print)